# use middleware in get request conditionally

Tags: express, middleware

i am using express routes. this is my request

```
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { celebrate, Joi, Segments } from "celebrate";

const route = Router();

export default (app: Router) => {
route.get("/:id",
    celebrate({
      [Segments.PARAMS]: Joi.object({
        id: Joi.string().required().label("Store Id")
      })
    }),
    basicAuth, //a middleware
    asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      // some operations.
      return res.status(202).json(storeDetails);
    })
  );
}
```

here how can i use the `basicAuth` middleware conditionally such that `basicAuth` is used when id=="me" else another middleware `isAuth` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the middleware manually if your conditional is met:

```
route.get("/:id",
    celebrate({
      [Segments.PARAMS]: Joi.object({
        id: Joi.string().required().label("Store Id")
      })
    }),
    asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (req.params.id === "me") {
             // call basicAuth middleware manually
             basicAuth(req, res, err => {
                 if (err) {
                      // send error response here
                      next(err);
                 } else {
                      // continue processing here now that basicAuth has been verified
                 }
             });
        
        } else {
          // not "me"

          // some operations.
          return res.status(202).json(storeDetails);
        }
    })
  );
}
```